# Devise - Custom authenticate_user method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In addition to checking if a user's session is set when calling `authenticate_user` in the controller, I'd also like to check if the property `approved` is true

I could write a function in the `application_controller.rb` file and call it before each controller.

Is it possible for me to add this check to the `authenticate_user` method to also check for this?

Comment: I wont post the answer as you can. But why you want to do that? Makes no sense to use Devise in this case.

Comment: I was thinking of overriding the method `authenticate_user` to also accomplish this since users who are not approved should not be able to access the system

Answer (score 0):

You can do a patch like:

```
module Devise
  module Controllers
    module Helpers
      def authenticate_user!
        #do some code here
      end
    end
  end
end
```

See how Devise uses [Warden](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb) and add new [strategy](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Strategies).

Hope this helps. If you are stuck. Let us know.

Comment: Aplogies, where exactly would I add this code, to which file? I'm sorry I'm a bit of noob!

Comment: If you are new to Devise, you need to do more reading to perform these patching or do not patch anything at all. I refer to this file: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb